# Form validation - do I do this step on the front end or back end? REACT

Tags: reactjs, validation

I am trying to find the most efficient way to validate the form. Should do this step below on the front end or backend or both?:

```
  handleFormSubmission = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const credentials = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    if (
      this.state.password !== this.state.passwordConfirm &&
      this.state.password.trim()
    ) {
      this.setState({
        errorPasswordConfirm: "Passwords do not match.",
      });
    } else if (!this.state.username && !this.state.username.trim()) {
      this.setState({
        errorUsername: "Please provide username",
      });
    
etc..
```

Or should I implement this validation on the backend and just display an error from the console. However, I would like the input to update in realtime without sending API call. E.g. as soon as the password has length that's correct I would like to remove the error message.

```
outer.post("/signup", shouldNotBeLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ errorMessage: "Please provide your username." });
  }

  if (!password) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ errorMessage: "Please enter your password." });
  }
```

Comment: Its better if you can implement it on front-end as well as back-end

Comment: Thanks, so should I sort errors messages on the front end but still validate based on the same logic on the back end? Or is it recommended to still send messages to the front end?

Comment: For that you have to first check the values on frontend and if they are valid then only send the values to server and then validate those values on server again as frontend validations can easily bypassed